How can I change the choices of an Option depending on the writer of the slash command in pycord?
I want to give different people different Options in a slash command. Person 1 should get Options 1 2 and 3 and Person 2 should get Options 4, 5 and 6.
async def do_stuff(ctx, opt: commands.Option(str, choices=["Option1", "Option2","Option3"])):

async def do_stuff(ctx, opt: commands.Option(str, choices=myChoices[str(ctx.author)])):

This does of course not work.
How can I do that?
Thank You

Could you please expand your question? It is not clear what you want to achieve. Only your labels – "discord" and "pycord" – hint towards the topic of your question. pychord (question title) is an actual pypi package and not related to discord at all.

It is not possible to do this unfortunately, as per a discord limitation.
However, there is a workaround, which uses autocompletion. Here is an example:
import discord
from discord.commands import option


USER_1_ID = 2345678
USER_2_ID = 1234567

USER_1_CHOICES = ["banana", "strawberry", "orange"]
USER_2_CHOICES = ["bread", "salad", "cheese"]


async def my_autocomplete(ctx: discord.AutocompleteContext):
    if ctx.interaction.user.id == USER_1_ID:
        return [option for option in USER_1_CHOICES if option.startswith(ctx.value.lower())]
    elif ctx.interaction.user.id == USER_2_ID:
        return [option for option in USER_2_CHOICES if option.startswith(ctx.value.lower())]
    else:
        return [option for option in ["apple", "google", "microsoft"] if option.startswith(ctx.value.lower())]


@bot.slash_command(name="mycommand")
@option("opt", description="Pick an option!", autocomplete=discord.utils.basic_autocomplete(my_autocomplete), )
async def mycommand(ctx: discord.ApplicationContext, opt: str):
    # however, autocomplete does **not** verify that the options are valid for that user, so you have to implement your own check here.
    if (ctx.user.id == USER_1_ID and opt.lower() not in USER_1_CHOICES) or (ctx.user.id == USER_2_ID and opt.lower() not in USER_2_CHOICES):
        return await ctx.respond("Invalid option")
    await ctx.respond(f"Your option is {opt}")

Autocomplete allows you to have the autocompletion feature of the options' "choices" parameter, but in truth, it does not verify on the client side that the inputted option is part of the ones proposed, this is why you have to add your own check.
